# Gerar sequência de número de série autoincrement

Tags: mysql, python, python-2.7

Estou querendo gerar um numero de ordem de serviço, tenho o código, mas acontece quero que que ele consulte no banco de dados o ultimo numero da ordem de serviço que foi gerado.

Segue o código:

```
 def rangeOrdemServ(self):
        db = self.conexaoBanco()
        cursor = db.cursor()
        cursor.execute("select ordem_serv_num from ordem_serv where id = LAST_INSERT_ID()")
        dadosOrdemServ = cursor.fetchall()
        db.commit()
        global rec
        pStart = dadosOrdemServ
        pInterval = +1
        if (rec == 0):
            dado = pStart + pInterval
            self.entrOrdServ.insert(END,dado)
        else:
            rec += pInterval
        return rec
```

O erro:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "E:/CharIp ServerFTP_1.1/CharIP_1.1.7/Ordem_Servicos.py", line 152, in <module>
    sis(root)
  File "E:/CharIp ServerFTP_1.1/CharIP_1.1.7/Ordem_Servicos.py", line 21, in __init__
    self.telaOrdServ()
  File "E:/CharIp ServerFTP_1.1/CharIP_1.1.7/Ordem_Servicos.py", line 108, in telaOrdServ
    self.rangeOrdemServ()
  File "E:/CharIp ServerFTP_1.1/CharIP_1.1.7/Ordem_Servicos.py", line 119, in rangeOrdemServ
    dado = pStart + pInterval
TypeError: can only concatenate tuple (not "int") to tuple
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use o `cursor.lastrowid` para conseguir o último ID inserido no objeto do cursor , ou use `connection.insert_id()` para conseguir o ID do ultimo insert efetuado na conexão.

Porém como você falou que é um campo não auto incremento, seria legal você fazer um:

select max(ordem_serv_num), nome from ordem_serv

assim você teria o maior número cadastrado.

Comment: poderia me dar um exemplo: e que não tenho muita experiencia

Comment: @DiuniorRonaldoBrumLauser eu fiz exatamente isso use o cursor ja instanciado adicionando o lastrowid para validar ....

Comment: deu certo, porem ele me retorna 1 e nao a proxima sequencia. ex: 000570370 o proximo seria 000570371

Comment: @DiuniorRonaldoBrumLauser creio que agora te ajuda

Comment: resolvi essa questao obrigado, agora meu problema e pegar essa dados e somar ele a +1 para gerar a seguencia, ex: 000570370 para 000570371

Comment: @DiuniorRonaldoBrumLauser você pega o retorno e coloca +1, é bem simples, aproveite a assinale a pergunta como resolvida

Comment: vou criar outro topico para ver pois ja peguei o retorno e adicionei mais um so que nao da certo

Comment: Perfeito @DiuniorRonaldoBrumLauser é legal separar perguntar por tópicos assim fica mais facil de se achar

Answer (score 1):

Conforme a mensagem de erro, [`cursor.fetchall`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-python/en/connector-python-api-mysqlcursor-fetchall.html) retorna uma lista de *tuplas*, logo a concatenação que você quer fazer não é possível.

Como [mencionado pelo Otto](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/156597/6454), você pode usar [`cursor.lastrowid`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-python/en/connector-python-api-mysqlcursor-lastrowid.html) para retornar o valor desejado.

```
# ....
pStart = cursor.lastrowid
pInterval += 1

if (rec == 0):
    dado = pStart + pInterval
    self.entrOrdServ.insert(END,dado)
else:
    rec += pInterval
```

Comment: Curti sua resposta mais elaborada que a minha

Comment: retorna o numero 1 e nao a praxima sequencia de numeros ex: 000570370 o proximo seria 000570371

Comment: @DiuniorRonaldoBrumLauser Está correto. `lastrowid` vai retornar o valor gerado de acordo com a coluna de auto-incremento.

Comment: na verdade eu preciso consultar a ultima sequencia cadastrada no banco e gerar a proxima e inserir na minha Entry, so que essa coluna nao é auto-incremento.